# This monster $\int\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$ is giving me headaches. How to approximate?

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms, taylor-expansion, approximation

This integral is giving me a headache:

$$\int_{-b}^{b}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$

where $f(x)=(c + d - e)\text{sech}(ab)\cosh(a x)+(c-d)\text{csch}(ab)\sinh(a x) + e$

I could not come up with any general or $f$-specific way of approximating it. While Euler’s did not simplify much, a clever use of Taylor expansion might help. By approximation, I mean a general approximated form of solution (without having specific values). Any effort is greatly appreciated?

Comment: Does $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}~dx=\ln(|f(x)|)$ help? Using this and partial integration you get $\int_{-b}^b \frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}~dx=b(\ln(|f(b)|)-\ln(|f(-b)|))-\int_{-b}^b \ln(|f(x)|)~dx$.

Comment: Here is what the monster actually look like: $\int_{-b}^{b}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\int_{-b}^{b}\frac{ax((c + d - e)\text{sech}(ab)\sinh(a x)+(c-d)\text{csch}(ab)\cosh(a x) + e)}{(c + d - e)\text{sech}(ab)\cosh(a x)+(c-d)\text{csch}(ab)\sinh(a x). + e}dx$

Comment: @MundronSchmidt I do not think so. The original problem is actually to calculate $\int_{-b}^{b}ln(f(x))dx$. To take that, I have to deal with the current integral (in the problem). It is like a circular loop, I do not know which way is easier.

Comment: @JohnButler: I would suggest that the integral with the $\ln$ is simpler.

Comment: @Fabian I think so. Can you kindly provide a compact approximation for $\int\ln(f(x))dx$. I've been struggling with it for a week.

Comment: One can only find approximations, in specific limits. So you should tell us which of the many constants $a,b,c,d,e$ is larger or small. In particular, you will be able to get $f(x)$ on the form $\alpha \cosh(a x + \beta) + \gamma$ and we should know which of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ is the largest, smallest, and how they compare to $a$.

Comment: @Fabian Understand. I'm seeking for a approximated form of solution, indeed (not the actual approximated value). Something like Taylor expansion.

Comment: @yves-daoust Why did you delete your answer without saying anything? It's not professional to do that I guess. Please explain if it was wrong (or what?) to avoid misleading the community including me :) Thanks.